# Get total of all data attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically loading some of the content within my page and would like to get a total of all the data-attributes.

First the elements are cloned and appended

```
$('.chip').on('click', function () {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('.chipPlacement');
});
```

Then I have written a function that should get the totals

```
function chipsBet() {
  var redchip = $('.chipPlacement .chipValue.r').data() || 0;
  var bluechip = $('.chipPlacement .chipValue.b').data() || 0;
  var orangechip = $('.chipPlacement .chipValue.o').data() || 0;

  var total = redchip.chipValue + bluechip.chipValue + orangechip.chipValue;
  return total;

}
```

Before I append the elements the HTML looks like

```
<div class="chipPlacement"></div>
```

and once appended the HTML structure is

```
 <div class="chipPlacement">
     <div class="chip red">
       <div class="chipValue r" data-chip-value="1">1</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I need to listen for the DOM structure the change and then fire the `chipsBet()` function, but I'm not sure how to get this to work. I can't use `.on('change')` as that only applies to `input`, `textarea`  and `select`.

I have tried firing the `chipsBet` function within the `.chip.on('click')` but I get `NaN` returned.

How can I get the `data-attribute-values` for the new elements in the DOM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: call  `chipsBet()` inside `$('.chip').on('click',`

Comment: well thats what i originally done but i get NaN returned

Comment: Are you converting the values to ints with parseInt()? When originally returned, they're strings.

Comment: Well, lets say the data attribute isn't defined, and you end up with `0`, so what is `0.chipValue` supposed to get ?

Comment: @vch - when using jQuery's data, the data returned would be whatever format fits, for numbers it would be of type number, not string.

Comment: @Jack - ***NO*** -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wo0k1xno/**

Comment: I thought that data() would take all data-attributes and put them into an object? http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a blue or orange chip, you're effectively trying to get `.chipValue` from `0` which is `undefined` and adding it to another number gives you `NaN`.

You can simply iterate over all `.chipValue` elements within the placement element like so:

```
function chipsBet() 
{
  var total = 0;

  $('.chipPlacement .chipValue').each(function() {
    total += $(this).data('chipValue');
  });

  return total;
}
```

Comment: thank you, great refactoring there, though everyones contribution has helped me, so thank you to all

Comment: how come chipValue isnt chip-value, or does it not matter?

Comment: Ah, so much better than mine! I often overlook just how simplistic you can make jQuery ^-^

Comment: @Richlewis Both should work (perhaps `chip-value` is more portable, not sure), but you can choose whichever you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, you altered your initial question.. carrying on.

```
<div class='chipPlacement'>
    <div class='chip red'>
        <div class='chipValue' data-chip-value='1'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then to read your data attributes, you could do something like this.

```
$('.chip').on('click', function () {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.chipPlacement');
    chipsBet();
});

function chipsBet() {
    var redchipVal = parseInt($('.chipValue .r').data('chip-value')) || 0;
    var bluechipVal = parseInt($('.chipValue .b').data('chip-value')) || 0;
    var orangechipVal = parseInt($('.chipValue .o').data('chip-value')) || 0;

    var total = redchipVal + bluechipVal + orangechipVal;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i thought .data() would convert for you, my misinterpretation it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like bellow. It will call the function every time any change will in div `.chipPlacement`.

```
$('.chipPlacement').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    console.log('Div modified');
});
```

You can say for your problem

```
$('.chipPlacement').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
     chipsBet();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/38/)